# Include HTML files in Laravel 5 blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have created a laravel app where I am loading the product list from database. I am able to get this list very easily with larvel.

I am facing problem while adding search box to blade page. Since, PHP is server side, whenever user chose a product in search box I have to hit server to get the same data for single product and refresh product list in blade page.

My query is, do I have the option of loading html files(partials) which I can load using blade view. My logic is using ajax call in html files to retrieve product list, store it at client side and perform client side operations.

I know I have option of using Angular with laravel but I don't need all functionalities and overhead(routes,directive,what not) of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you facing, exactly? You're using ajax already, so just update the DOM when you receive your response. Include a partial view file with the HTML for a single item, but hide it until the user gets a single item, then show it and set the appropriate values.

I don't particularly like that approach, however. That's a big reason what Vue, Angular, React, etc. are there for.